# 2004 f150 4x4 causes for errant hi temp reading

Tags: ford, overheating, f-150

Recent engine replacement & transmission overhaul
Have replaced thermostat & coolant with no effect
Will return to normal reading after only 10 second shutdown

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure the radiator was bled correctly? There may be an air pocket in it which is interfering with how the gauge is reading.